# animateKeyframes frame height animation takes longer than origin point

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a case where I need to animate two views, ones position and the others height when the keyboard is shown. The view that has its change in height lags behind the others change in position. When I change the height change to a position change they are in sync again. Why does changing the frame height using an animation appear to lag behind the change in y point

This code takes longer to animate

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
  self.frame.size.height += deltaY
},completion: nil)
```

than

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
  self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
},completion: nil)
```

when everything else is identical in value

Comment: You have to animate your views with x and y coordinate not with height and width and what is deltaY and what did you pass duration in an animate method?

Comment: Everything outside of the line ` self.frame.xxx += deltaY` is identical in value. Also if you can only animate x, y then how do you animate height?

Comment: The issue with animating the y is that it leads the view to be partially off screen and cut off, so I need the views height to change so that it all remains on screen